# How to get the control that was clicked from the caller form?

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-365-operations

Using the following code in a chain of command class, I am able to find the caller form:

```
Object caller = this.args().caller();
```

How  do I go about finding the control that was clicked in the caller form from chain of commands?

Comment: Could you show more of the chain of command class? What class/method are you extending with this?

Comment: @FH-Inway I am extending the run() method of the ProdCalcTrans form. The CoC class is very simple as it stands, I verify if the args().caller() object is my custom form (ProdOrderTolerance form), if so I want to focus on a specific ProdCalcTrans tab page. The reason why I want to note which control (menu item) i clicked on the caller form is because two different procedures must be done depending which button I clicked on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how:

```
this.args().callerFormControl().name();
```